# Can't push to fossil repo hosted on chiselapp

Tags: fossil

I have a fossil repository on chiselapp.com. I have used it for several years on a variety of machines.

I have recently cloned the repo onto a new machine running Windows 10 and fossil 2.8 [f8d7f76bfd]. When I try to push changes to chiselapp, I get the error

> missing or incorrect password for user "username"

I've configured the remote url as

> https://`<`username`>`:`<`password`>`@chiselapp.com/user/`<`chiselapp-user`>`/repository/`<`repo-name`>`

which fossil reports as

> https://`<`username`>`@chiselapp.com/user/`<`chiselapp-user`>`/repository/`<`repo-name`>`

without the password. I assume this is a security feature of fossil.

I'm confident that I've set the correct password for `<`username`>` since I can use that password in chiselapp once I've logged in as `<`chiselapp-user`>`.

After

> fossil push

as well as the error message locally, there is **no** entry in the access log on chiselapp.

Please can someone tell me where I'm going wrong and how to set myself up to be able to push changes. Apart from the username I can't see any configuration difference between a Windows 7 machine from which I can push changes and the Windows 10 machine from which I can't. Both usernames are set up with **bs** capabilities on chiselapp.

Thanks for any help.

---

Update (10-Aug-2019)

I'm in the middle of building a new laptop running Linux Mint. I've downloaded fossil (now version 2.9) and wasn't suprised that it was a bit of a struggle to be able to push to chiselapp, but I managed it eventually.

I've put fossil 2.9 onto the Windows 10 machine and have configured the remote url **exactly** the same as on the mint machine; I'm confident of this because I can see both command-lines. I still get the error when I try to `push` from the Windows machine.

(A slight difference between mint and Windows 10 operation is that on Mint I see a prompt

> remember password (Y/n)?

which doesn't appear on Windows. Is this a porting-related bug?)

Comment: Just in case: Were you using it with 2.8 before?  (There are significant incompatibilities between 1.x and 2.x versions of fossil.)

Comment: Right now, I'm sitting on another machine running Linux and fossil 2.6 which can push to chiselapp ok. According to the page footers, chiselapp.com is running fossil 1.34, dated 2015-11-02, which sounds a little surprising.

Comment: As for chiselapp.com I suppose having to keep existing repos compatible to the possibility of their users still using 1.x keeps them from updating.  Once a repo is (even accidentally) upgraded to 2.x it is no longer possible to use from 1.x

Answer (score 0):

I asked about this on the [forum](https://www.fossil-scm.org/forum/forum) over at the [fossil website](https://www.fossil-scm.org).

It [turned out](https://www.fossil-scm.org/forum/forumpost/69e0e711ac) that my problems were caused by using the Windows version of fossil from a cygwin window rather than the version that comes as part of the cygwin distribution.

Now that I have installed the later version of fossil and am using that from the cygwin command line, everything is working beautifully.